# Navigation in app fails across different composables

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm following https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-my-city?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-compose-unit-4-pathway-3%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-compose-my-city

and I'm trying to put together an app that has both worlds of the codelabs I went through so far:

1. navigation
2. multi screen adaptable app

I haven't yet integrated navigation as I don't know how to include it without breaking the current multi screen adaptable capability of the app.

So far, the behavior is as follows:

1. In compact mode, the app correctly displays categories only; however, when clicking on a given category instead of the list of recommendations to be displayed (which when clicked lead to the recommendation itself in all details), the recommendation itself (summarized) is shown - see below screenshot (first exemplifies listing of categories; second what happened when clicking on a given category)

Listing categories

[image]

2. In expanded mode (tablet), it correctly shows the categories side by side recommendations and the expanded recommendation, however, clicking on a category won't filter the list of recommendations; moreover, clicking on a category will open the recommendation itself (see below screenshots)

Clicking on a category, opens up the recommendation itself (the default recommendation and not the one associated with the category) instead of refreshing the displayed side by side list of recommendations (middle)

---

I've tried implementing navigation, however, I can't see how to integrate navigation and multi-screen size adaptation of the app.

Expected behavior in compact mode:

1. List of categories is displayed as Card composables
2. Click on a category displays a list of recommendations associated with that category
3. Click on a recommendation opens the recommendation in expanded view with back button available

Expected behavior in expanded mode (tablet):

1. List of categories, recommendations and expanded recommendation is shown side by side; default category is first in the list, this displays all the recommendations associated with it (middle) and the first recommendation in the list (expanded mode, right most)
2. A click on a category displays the list of recommendations (middle) associated with that category; the recommendation shown right most (expanded mode) is the first in recommendations list
3. A click on any recommendation from the recommendations list (middle) will show that recommendation in expanded mode (right most)

How can I filter correctly between categories and recommendations, showing the first recommendation as default from the recommendations list, and show the recommendation on the right most side when a user clicks on the recommendation from the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/alghe-global/Kotlin/tree/ff88e2cc1c97d761c29047c27770bb2d0aab27a1/AndroidBasicsCourse/MyCity) on GitHub